# Fastest way to compare string to a large arrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a file processing programme.

In it I have a method that checks a filename (string) against an `ArrayList` of filenames. The idea is that the programme doesn't have to process files that are in the `ArrayList` already.

The problem I have is that the `ArrayList` can be very large (16,000 elements) and I am iterating through around the same number of files so that the checking of each file against the `ArrayList` is taking too much time. I think this is because I am using `.contains`.

Is there a more efficient (i.e. faster) way of performing these String to `ArrayList` comparisons with very large arrayLists or should I be storing in a different data structure?

My code:

```
public class Iterator {
    static ArrayList<String> myFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String filename= "/Files/FilesLogged.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException, BackingStoreException {       
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)),2048);
        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            myFiles.add(line);
        }
            reader.close();
        }  

    public static void loopthrough(String folderName) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException{
        System.out.println("This is the loopthrough folderName"+folderName);
        File dir = new File(folderName);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();        

            if (directoryListing != null) {                   
                for (File child : directoryListing) {
                    if(!myFiles.contains(child.getName())){

             System.out.println("THE FILE NAMES ARE"+child.getName().toString());

                                           }
                                                     }
                                                          }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Right now it's unreadable.

Comment: Why not use a HashSet instead?

Comment: Is a hashset faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Set (HashSet or TreeSet).

This data structures allow you to check the existence of the element in it for time O(1) or O(log n) respectively.

ArrayList compares the value to each element, so it is O(n).

I would recommend you to use HashSet. The overhead for using it is about ~70 bytes for each entry.

Comment: HashSet supports the contains method. So I can still use this method and get the faster comparisons?

Comment: @SebastianZeki, yes. Although the method has the same name and checks if element is stored it works absolutely other way under the hood and works much faster.

Comment: OK, Thanks. Thats great.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use a search algorithm. A simple start would be a binary search. This will give you a processing time of lg(n) down from n. (Ex. 10 steps instead of 1024);

If the ArrayList does not change so often, you can do that search at anytime using another thread (if you have the information or time to do it before). And after you found a result you can cache it, you will be deleting the cache if the ArrayList changed